# What does the line "Bangkok has him now" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-hangover-2

In the movie [The Hangover 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hangover_Part_II), when Teddy was lost, the people they met (even the  Interpol police officer) kept saying **"Bangkok has him now"**. What did they actually mean by that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They were anthropomorphing the city of Bangkok for effect. In other words they were talking about the city as if it was a person. Bangkok has a certain reputation for lawlessness (true or not). So when Teddy was lost in Bangkok, some people thought that he was lost for good and that his friends will never find him again. Bangkok has caught Teddy, and is not going to let him go. Bangkok has him now.

Comment: so that is why, according to the movie Bangkok was filled with different syndicates which if I understood what you said its like they represent Bangkok and The friends of Teddy assumed that they(the Syndicates) have Teddy

Answer (score 6):

After watching that movie I think it's just a complimentary dialogue for **what happens in Vegas stays in Vegas** of the previous film. They need a strong dialogue which compliments Bangkok and should be catchy. And I think it's not a new phrase/dialogue and it means somebody is lost in the glimpses of Bangkok.

Comment: While I understand what you want to say, I'm not sure *"glimpses"* is the word you wanted to use. If it is, then excuse my mere dictionary-based misunderstanding.

Comment: @ChristianRau my English is not that good but i still thought glimpses is the word , which i want to use but if you can suggest any better word in that place then you are all welcome.

Comment: Since I don't know the *exact* meaning you want to convey with this word and am myself not a native speaker, I cannot offer many alternatives. I just wanted to make sure you are completely sure that it is the appropriate word.

Comment: It's hard to explain an metaphor in a language that is not your native one.

Comment: @CineEsgoto true.

Comment: @AnkitSharma:  Perhaps you can mention the word or phrase from your native language precisely capturing the intended effect so someone here will attempt to translate it?  I'll have a go myself.